# Linking Error with Confluent Kafka Go Package and MSYS2 GCC on Windows 11

Tags: windows, go, gcc, apache-kafka, msys2

I'm encountering a linking error while building a Golang application on Windows 11 64-bit, with MSYS2 GCC installed. The issue arises when I try to use the `confluent-kafka-go` package.

**Error Message:**

```
$ go build main.go
# command-line-arguments
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_error.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp__vsnprintf_s'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_mock.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp__vsnprintf_s'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_txnmgr.c.obj):(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `__imp__vsnprintf_s'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_idempotence.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp__vsnprintf_s'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_aux.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp__vsnprintf_s'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(rdkafka_admin.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): more undefined references to `__imp__vsnprintf_s' follow
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Thadeu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_windows.a(regexp.c.obj):(.text+0x29fe): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This seems to be a linker (`ld.exe`) issue, as it's unable to find references for `__imp__vsnprintf_s` and `_setjmp` in the libraries I'm using.

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows 11 64-bit
- Golang version: 1.21.5
- GCC version: 13.2.0
- Confluent Kafka Go Package version: [v2.3.0](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/v2@v2.3.0/kafka)

**What I've Tried:**

1. Updating GCC to the latest version through MSYS2. [MSYS2 Guide](https://www.msys2.org/)
2. Reinstalling `confluent-kafka-go` package with `go get -u`.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I've ensured that `CGO_ENABLED` is set to `1` and that the C compiler is correctly included in the PATH.

**Question:**
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into resolving these linker errors? Any suggestions on additional steps or alternative configurations that might work for this setup?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, all i did was deleting this path `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\` in system environment variables and change it to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, I think the referenced to '__imp__vsnprintf_s' in ucrt64 is different from mingw64. In my case, the code is working again.

I almost forgot, i also run this command `$ pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain` in MSYS2 MINGW64 shell and through default installation process. Then I downgrade my go version to `go1.19.13` from `go1.22.0`

Comment: It doesn't matter in what shell you run `pacman`. What matters is what packages you install. To get stuff in `mingw64/bin`, you need `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` (without `-ucrt-`).